# Google Map looks stretchy

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image: stretchy map]

Hello, I'm implementing this [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers) to my site but it looks so weird and stretchy.
How to make it normal but stay full width and height in its column.
any solution?

currently, my map inside flexbox column, does it takes effect for the map?

```css
#map-canvas{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdl-grid p-0">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try changing the height to auto

Comment: height : auto could make the map disappear @RachelGallen - give the map an absolute height not a relative one

Comment: the #map-canvas becomes height: 0

Comment: It is likely a CSS problem.  Something in your CSS is probably being applied to the map.  Can't tell what without a [mcve] (and if you make a mcve, you might discover the issue)

Comment: @JaromandaX i give height: 500px and width: 500px but not working https://tppr.me/ul2fc

Comment: without all the CSS and HTML (and javascript) it's hard to say what you are doing wrong

Comment: @vanio178 It's difficult to tell the problem without seeing the rest of the html/css

Comment: i'm sorry, finally i hit the problem, it was my fault. there's main container and i put a style for images inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i hit the problem, this was my fault . 
but maybe this can be useful for the future

```html
<div id="map-wrapper"> <!-- in this wrapper i put a style for images inside it -->
  <div class="mdl-grid p-0">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i put a style for images inside it, `#map-wrapper img{min-width: 740px}` so this affects all images inside the iframe map too, i was tought that map just a canvas

Answer (score -2):

The map is currently at 100% screen width and height. You need to set Height and Width to the width
of your column.

```
#map-canvas{
    height: 30vh;
    width: 30vw;
}
```

Also look into the vh and vw at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp.
This helps width setting width and height to the devices width and height.

Comment: This solution worked in my case, if your going to down vote, at least leave a comment educating the person.